# Arduino Master-Slave Pins

Tags: i2c, wire-library

Can I change the pins on the communication for a Master-Slave arduino Wire transmission? I want to communicate between 2 arduinos, but on one of them A4&A5 are taken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot. Wire uses hardware I<sup>2</sup>C, and on the Uno only A4 and A5 are connected to the TWI peripheral on the MCU. You will need to either switch to a bit-bang I<sup>2</sup>C implementation or change the protocol you're using.

Answer (score 1):

To complete Ignacio's answer, there's indeed no other hardware I2C on AVR Arduinos.

The only options you have to use other pins is:

- to use bitbang i2c, which is way slower ;
- or you can switch to the Arduino Due which features two TWI ports ;
- or you can use an SPI to I2C serial bridge such has [that one](http://www.silabs.com/products/interface/spitoi2c/Pages/default.aspx).